# Making a tabular table fit the page width

Tags: tables, width

I am new to LaTeX. I have put together a regression table using the table generator website. I am at the final stage where I want to make the table as wide as the page, but I'm not sure how to do this. Could anyone suggest a solution on how best to go around this?

The code table and the environment is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\small
\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. Praesent et ex et nisl mattis pulvinar at non lectus.}
\label{tab:my-tab5}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccccc@{}}
  \cmidrule(l){2-9}
  \textbf{} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 3}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 4}} \\ \midrule
  Occupational class &
    \textbf{Coefficient\textsuperscript{a}} &
    \textbf{95\% CI\textsuperscript{b}} &
    \textbf{Coefficient\textsuperscript{a}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{95\% CI}} &
    \textbf{Coefficient} &
    \textbf{95\% CI\textsuperscript{b}} &
    \textbf{Coefficient\textsuperscript{a}} &
    \textbf{95\% CI\textsuperscript{b}} \\
  \textbf{Father's occupational class at age 5} &
   &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
   &
   &
   \\
\hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,980) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \hspace{5mm}{I Professional/II Intermediate}\\ \hspace{5mm}{III Skilled (non-manual or manual)}\\ \hspace{5mm}{IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled}\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.004\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.009, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
   &
  \textless{}0.001; \textless{}0.001 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
  0.025; 0.025 &
   &
  0.003; 0.004 &
   &
  0.002; 0.002 \\
\hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,925) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\hspace{5mm}{I Professional/II Intermediate}\\ \hspace{5mm}{III Skilled (non-manual or manual)}\\ \hspace{5mm}{IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled}\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ -0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.36\\ 1.01\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.743; 0.568} &
   &
  0.123; 0.045 &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.411; \textless{}0.001} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.261; 0.408} \\
\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5} &
    &
    &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
    &
    &
    &
    &
    \\
  \hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,485) &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
  \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\hspace{5mm}{Vocational/degree and higher}\\ \hspace{5mm}{A-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{2mm}{Vocational/O-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{5mm}{No qualification}\end{tabular}} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular}} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
  p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
    &
    \textless{}0.001; \textless{}0.001 &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
    \textless{}0.001; 0.008 &
    &
    \textless{}0.001; 0.002 &
    &
    0.005; 0.001 \\
  \hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,412) &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\hspace{2mm}{Vocational/degree and higher}\\ \hspace{5mm}{A-level/equivalent}\\ Vocational/O-level/equivalent\\ No qualification\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular}} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 1.46\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
  p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    0.304; 0.064 &
    &
    072; 0.046 &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    0.160; 0.305 &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    0.078; - \\
  \textbf{Father's highest qualification at age 5} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,343) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\hspace{5mm}{Vocational/degree and higher}\\ \hspace{5mm}{A-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{5mm}{Vocational/O-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{5mm}{No qualification}\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ -0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ -0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
   &
  0.304; 0.064 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
  0.899; 0.698 &
   &
  0.715; 0.368 &
   &
  0.642; 0.287 \\
\hspace{2mm}{Female} (N=2,286) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\hspace{5mm}{Vocational/degree and higher}\\ \hspace{5mm}{A-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{5mm}{Vocational/O-level/equivalent}\\ \hspace{5mm}{No qualification}\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.002\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.002\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.00 (ref)\\ 0.08\\ 0.00\\ -0.08\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.80\\ 0.00, 0.00\end{tabular} \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  0.123; 0.020 &
   &
  0.003; \textless{}0.001 &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  0.056; 0.009 &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  0.986; 0.866 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize      
\item
\textsuperscript{a} Duis leo ante, malesuada sit amet magna at, dictum feugiat dui; \textsuperscript{b} CI: Confidence Interval; \textsuperscript{c} P-value: p-value from a likelihood ratio test of the overall association; \textsuperscript{d} P-trend: p-value not presented for relationship where there was significant deviation from linearity
\end{tablenotes}    

\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

table currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{....}`, in other words use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` in order to make a table fit onto a page. This approach will only lead to inconsistent and in many cases, such as yours, illegibly small font sizes. There are definitely better ways, see for example the general suggestions/approaches presented in the answer to [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one uses `\scriptsize` (rather than just `\small`) along with a basic font size of 10pt, if one is willing to reduce the value of `\arraystretch` (1.4 seems excessive), and if one uses fairly narrow margins (say, 2.5cm), it is *just* possible to the table -- including the caption and the `tablenotes` part -- fit inside the textblock.

I can't help but make an additional comment: The code you use to generate the table is of really low quality. How did you come up with that code? I've tried to improve the code quality in the answer below, but it's still not truly good.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaytable' env.
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\mytabC[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mytabL[1]{\hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} % 1.4 is excessive

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. }
\label{tab:my-tab5}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
\toprule
  &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 4} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
  Occupational class &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI          &
    Coefficient          & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's occupational class at age 5}} & \\
   Female ($N=2{,}980$) & \\
   \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.004\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.009, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & 0.025; 0.025 & & 0.003; 0.004 & & 0.002; 0.002 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}925$) & \\
  \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ -0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.36\\ 1.01}} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.743; 0.568 & & 0.123; 0.045 & & 0.411; <0.001 & & 0.261; 0.408 \\

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5}} & \\
  Female ($N=2{,}485$) & \\
  \mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ A-level/equiv.\\ \hspace{2mm}Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & <0.001; 0.008 & & <0.001; 0.002 & & 0.005; 0.001 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}412$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 1.46} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
    \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
       & 0.304; 0.064 & & 072; 0.046 & & 0.160; 0.305 & & 0.078; — \\

  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's highest qualification at age 5}} \\ 
Female ($N=2{,}343$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ -0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ -0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
   & 0.304; 0.064 & & 0.899; 0.698 & & 0.715; 0.368 & & 0.642; 0.287 \\
\addlinespace
Female ($N=2{,}286$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.002\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.002\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.08\\ 0.00\\ -0.08} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.80\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.123; 0.020 & & 0.003; <0.001 & & 0.056; 0.009 & & 0.986; 0.866 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}     
\item[a] Duis leo ante, malesuada sit amet magna at, dictum feugiat dui; 
\item[b] CI: Confidence Interval; 
\item[c] P-value: p-value from a likelihood ratio test of the overall association; 
\item[d] P-trend: p-value not presented for relationship where there was significant deviation from linearity
\end{tablenotes}    
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped solve my issue and pick up some new approaches. I am new to LaTex, So picking up a lot of this stuff as I go along. I have the table on the table generator website and then amended it based on the styles I want it to be in.

Comment: @MohamedYusuf - In my experience, the code generated by tablegenerator.com is nearly unmaintainable. That is, it might be just ok (though never any better, and quite often worse than "just ok"), but it so convoluted and baroque that if you ever have to modify the table just a bit, it's nearly impossible to do so by hand. Instead, you'll have to start all over again. I think you should make an effort to learn the basics of LaTeX tables; the payoff will be that fairly quickly, you can create all but the most difficult tables on your own, without the tablegenerators.com crutch.

Comment: That is a very helpful advice. I will definitely invest in learning the latex table code. Any resources you could suggest, specially since there are so many different types of table packages?

Comment: I would start with Tobias Oetiker's [Not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf). For a long list of resources for LaTeX learners, please see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

A place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\small
\begin{TableNotes}[para]
\footnotesize      
\item[a] Duis leo ante, malesuada sit amet magna at, dictum feugiat dui; 
\item[b] CI: Confidence Interval; 
\item[c] P-value: p-value from a likelihood ratio test of the overall association; 
\item[d] P-trend: p-value not presented for relationship where there was significant deviation from linearity
\end{TableNotes}
  \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{\;\;}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xcccccccc@{}}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. Praesent et ex et nisl mattis pulvinar at non lectus.}
\label{tab:my-tab5}\\
  \toprule
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 3}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 4}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
  Occupational class &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI} &
    \textbf{Coeff.}          & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. Praesent et ex et nisl mattis pulvinar at non lectus. - continued from previous page}\\
  \toprule
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 3}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Model 4}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
  Occupational class &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI} &
    \textbf{Coeff.}          & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} &
    \textbf{Coeff.\tnote{a}} & \textbf{95\% CI\tnote{b}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
    \endfoot
  \multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's occupational class at age 5}} \\* \addlinespace
  \textit{Female (N=2,980)}  \\*
I Professional/II Intermediate     & 0.00 (ref) & —           & 0.00 (ref) & —          & 0.00 (ref) & —          & 0.00 (ref) & —          \\
III Skilled (non-manual or manual) & 0.004      & 0.009, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 \\
IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled      & 0.00       & 0.009, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 & 0.00       & 0.00, 0.00 \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) 
  &  & \textless{}0.001; \textless{}0.001 
  &  & 0.025; 0.025 
  &  & 0.003; 0.004 
  &  &  0.002; 0.002 \\ \addlinespace
\textit{Female (N=2,925)}\\*
I Professional/II Intermediate     & & & & & & & &   \\
III Skilled (non-manual or manual) & & & & & & & &   \\
IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled      & & & & & & & &   \\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) 
  & & & & & & & &   \\
  \midrule 
 
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5}}\\* \addlinespace
\textit{Female (N=2,485)}\\*
Vocational/degree and higher \\
A-level/equivalent \\
Vocational/O-level/equivalent\\
No qualification\\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) \\ \addlinespace
\textit{Female (N=2,412)}\\*
Vocational/degree and higher \\
A-level/equivalent \\
Vocational/O-level/equivalent\\
No qualification\\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5}}\\* \addlinespace
\textit{Female (N=2,343)}\\*
Vocational/degree and higher \\
A-level/equivalent \\
Vocational/O-level/equivalent\\
No qualification\\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) \\ \addlinespace
\textit{Female (N=2,286)}\\*
Vocational/degree and higher \\
A-level/equivalent \\
Vocational/O-level/equivalent\\
No qualification\\
p-values (overall\textsuperscript{c}; test for trend\textsuperscript{d}) \\
\end{xltabular}%
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```